# JavaScript: в чем разница между событиями onclick и addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли разница между использованием события `onclick` и `addEventListener`?

```
document.getElementById('id1').onclick = function() {
    alert('Спасибо');
}

document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert('Пожалуйста');
})
```

Результат работы тот же самый, но:

`onclick` - пишут, что поддерживаетя всеми браузерами;

`addEventListener` - за исключением IE8 и ниже.

В описаниях и решениях я больше вижу использование `addEventListener`? Почему так, ведь главное сейчас это кроссбраузерность и `onclick` ее вроде как обеспечивает?

Comment: например: попробуй задать несколько обработчиков с помощью onclick. Кроме того, для IE8 и ниже аналог _addEventListener_ - _attachEvent_

Comment: На IE8 всем плевать, а кому не плевать, для тех attachEvent это тот же самый addEventListener, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[С большого SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick).
В основном проблема в том, что может быть только один обработчик у `on...`, но поддерживает `IE8` (сейчас уже вряд ли стоит пыжится из-за него).
Когда стало ясно что одного обработчика мало, вендоры создали свои реализации.  W3C стандартизировать предложили `addEventListener`, а в мелкософте, как всегда, придумали свой костыль, с [очень странными особенностями](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/comparison#osobennosti-attachevent).
Впрочем, стандарт они, в конце концов, тоже реализовали, так что всегда используйте `addEventListener`.
Если нужна поддержка старых `IE`, проще, наверное, в системе сборки переделать.